# TCP socket isn't reading

Tags: c#

```
private byte[] ResponseAsync(byte[] buffer, string ip, int port)
{
    byte[] buffer_ = new byte[10000]; // receiving buffer 10KB
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    //await write;
    int i = 0;

    while (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        i = stream.Read(buffer_, 0, 1024);
    }

    return buffer_.Take(i).ToArray();
}
```

the code was async but I thought I was doing somethign wrong so made it synchrone

Comment: Be aware that TCP doesn't provide *messages* - it provides an endless stream of bytes in both directions. At the moment your code *could* read one byte at a time (in theory) and continually overwrite that data in your buffer since you always supply the same buffer and tell the system to fill it from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the beginning of your buffer each time you do a read and will only return the data read in the last iteration of the `while` loop.

As such you'll need to increment `i` with the amount of data read and then use that as the offset when copying data in to your buffer.

```
private byte[] ResponseAsync(byte[] buffer, string ip, int port)
{
    byte[] buffer_ = new byte[10000]; // receiving buffer 10KB
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    //await write;
    int i = 0;

    while (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        // write data to the appropriate point in buffer_ and update i
        i += stream.Read(buffer_, i, 1024);
    }

    return buffer_.Take(i).ToArray();
}
```

Be aware though that if you receive more than 10,000 bytes this will throw an exception.

The chances are that you'll not read all the data from the stream as `stream.DataAvailable` will only say whether there's data available to be read not that the stream has finished.

Comment: Still doesn't work I opened wireshark to ensure the server is returning something, could I be missing the stream since I'm not writing async?

Comment: "could I be missing the stream...?" -- No; any response from the server is buffered. It's unclear why you're writing 10kB of garbage (uninitialized data) to the server, though.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe `buffer` is passed in and sent to server, while `buffer_` is filled by response from server. Although should really have commented on question, not my answer.